# Trying to place inventory TilePane within scrollable pane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane, hbox

Brand new to stackoverflow, so my apologies if I have posted incorrectly.

I have created an inventory system for a top down map based game. The inventory pane displays all the items carried by the character.

I have created individual HBoxes with a delete item button, however I have attempted to places the HBoxes within a scrollable pane.

Unfortunately the scroll bars do not seem to be appearing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
private void displayInvStructure() {

    this.setVgap(4);
    this.setHgap(4);
    this.setPadding(new Insets(1));
    this.setPrefColumns(4);
    this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff4a8; -fx-padding: 5; -fx-spacing: 5; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2px;");

    HBox itemTile[] = new HBox[31];
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete Item");
        deleteButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> { //Creates event when button clicked
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item has been deleted", null, 1);
        });

        itemTile[i] = new HBox(new Label("Item: " + i + "   "));
        itemTile[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        itemTile[i].setPadding(new Insets(5));
        itemTile[i].getChildren().add(deleteButton);
        itemTile[i].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        itemTile[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e5efff; -fx-border-color: black;");
        this.getChildren().add(itemTile[i]);

    }
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    sp.setFitToWidth(true);
    sp.setContent(this);

}
```

Comment: Where do you display the scrollpane?

Comment: Also, OT: don't mix Swing and JavaFX. Use an `Alert` instead of a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: You never add the `ScrollPane` to a scene/layout. This way it's never displayed in a scene. (BTW: adding a custom `Node` to a `ScrollPane` in one of it's own methods is a bad idea in most cases.)

Comment: Im trying to display the scroll pane within my inventory pane. The inventory pane is then displayed in my Main Class. Hope that makes sense. I'm new to Java so learning things step by step.